# rails include all associated data in get all request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get all records of a specific table with their associated data when called from the model. I've tried a number of different options but cant seem to figure it out.

I have a a rails structure where:
(assume all classes are inheriting from activerecord:base)

```
class Post 
    has_many :image
    has many :comment 
end 

class Image 
    belongs_to :post
end

class Comment 
    belongs_to :post
end
```

Basically I want to get all the posts with all associated data in my Post class (or model). For example:

```
    Post.all (but then here do something to include each post's images and comments)
```

I've tried these two options but they dont return the associated data

```
Post.all.eager_load(:image, :comment)
Blog2.all.includes(:image, :comment)
```

In my controller I have an index method

```
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    render json: @posts, :include => [:image, :comment]
  end
```

this index method works perfectly and includes the associated data with each record but when I try to do get all posts with their associated data in the model i cant get to to work. thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried `Post.joins([:image, :comment]).all` ? You can run ``Post.joins([:image, :comment]).to_sql` in `rails console` and see what `sql` is being generated.

Comment: And you need to use `render json: @posts.to_json( :include => [:image, :comment])` in order for you to export the associations to json.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're close. The `includes` method will preload the associated data, but won't actually present it to you with the results unless you specifically tell it to.

For example:

```
blog_records = Blog2.all.includes(:image, :comment)
blog_records_with_associations = blog_records.map do |record|
  record.attributes.merge(
    'image' => record.image,
    'comment' => record.comment
  )
end
```

This will convert the data into an array of hashes, suitable for publishing as json.

If you just need to access the associated records in Ruby, it's simpler:

```
blog_records = Blog2.all.include(:image, :comment)
first_image = blog_records.image     # preloaded, no SQL fired
first_comment = blog_records.comment # preloaded, no SQL fired
```

Comment: Just to point it out, the answer is only applicable to this specific case where the response is directly rendered from the controller as json.

Comment: @maxpleaner thank you, this answer is a life-saver! Is there a way to just get related record ids rather than entire records? I think i can restrict that with .pluck or such, but there's still extra SQL being made

Comment: @Rudi with `pluck` it only loads the data you specify. You can select any specific columns using the `select` method though